D3 scale works in v6 but not in v7
I have code using d3 v6.7.0 that sets up a scale like so:


const range = [0, 828.156];
const domain = [[300,1],[300,2],[300,3],[400,1],[400,2],[400,3],[400,4]]
const scale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(domain)
  .range(range);

// test 1: this works in both v6 and v7
const a = domain[3];
console.log('array a', a);
console.log('scaled a:', scale(a));

// test 2: declaring a new, identical array to the one above, 
// also works in v6
const b = [400, 1];
console.log('array b', b);
console.log('scaled b:', scale(b));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-cd6CHE+XWDQ33ElJqsi0MdNte3S+bQY819f7p3NUHgwQQLXSKjE4cPZTeGNI+vaxZynk1wVU3hoHmow3m089wA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



In d3 v7.9.0, this no longer works:


const range = [0, 828.156];
const domain = [[300,1],[300,2],[300,3],[400,1],[400,2],[400,3],[400,4]]

const scale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(domain)
  .range(range);

// test 1: this works in both v6 and v7
const a = domain[3];
console.log('array a', a);
console.log('scaled a:', scale(a));

// test 2:  declaring a new, identical array to the one above, 
// does not work in v7, but it does work in v6
const b = [400, 1];
console.log('array b', b);
console.log('scaled b:', scale(b));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.9.0/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-vc58qvvBdrDR4etbxMdlTt4GBQk1qjvyORR2nrsPsFPyrs+/u5c3+1Ct6upOgdZoIl7eq6k3a1UPDSNAQi/32A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>



Has something changed from v6 to v7, or what am I doing wrong?

D3 v7 uses InternMap:

Ordinal scales now use InternMap for domains; domain values are now uniqued by coercing to a primitive value via object.valueOf instead of coercing to a string via object.toString.

In v6 the domain would be coerced using object.toString:


console.log([400,1].toString() === [400,1].toString())



In v7 they use object.valueOf:


console.log([400,1].valueOf() === [400,1].valueOf())




This is a good answer.  @toms, for a little more context see here for a little more context on InternMap.

Thank you both. Reading up now - seems this will point to an approach that works though I don't quite know what that is yet. I can coerce each individual domain value to string when I set up the scale (and this works), but that seems hacky.

It looks like D3 v7.9.0 made a change in how the scaleBand function handles input data. For example, when you try to pass an array as ([400, 1]), it might not be interpreted correctly as an array with two elements [400, 1].
Corrected Version
const range = [0, 828.156];
const domain = [[300,1],[300,2],[300,3],[400,1],[400,2],[400,3],[400,4]];

const scale = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(domain)
  .range(range);



// corrected test 2 
const b = [400, 1];
console.log('array b', b);
console.log('scaled b:', scale(b));


This also returns undefined.

Good eye, thank you. You are right, there was no reason to wrap those array declarations in parentheses, that was a typo on my part (I've edited the question). But as @Mark points out, even without the parens the scale returns undefined in v7
